# Migration in rails 5 with jruby

Tags: postgresql, jruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I create a database via rake task successfully. But I have a problem while migrating my migration files for models. I always get the following problem related to postgres.

[image]

Comment: Please paste code of your migrations, there might be a issue with your migration file.

Comment: `class CreatePools < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :pools do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :pool_type
      t.text :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end`

Comment: Are you still having problems with your migration(s)?

Comment: Yes. I think there is a problem with jruby with postgres database in rails 5. I found some people have the same problem.